# jquery append() sporadically fails when I append a hidden input field with large value

Tags: jquery

I have a hidden input field with a large hidden value sent as string (around 1KB). On the client side, 
I do a formElement.append(hiddenInputElement) . Now this fails sporadically on a mobile device with low memory(64MB RAM). I suspect that the device is not able to do this due to a large value field.

Is there any way to get the appending done without incurring too much memory wrath? Or should I compress the value field and send the data across?

Also, is there any other alternative to append? Is there an easier way to copy the hidden value without taking up too much memory?

Answer (score 1):

The memory usage will certainly be the same whatever the way you add the data to the dom... Although, it might not be memory problem due to the 1k but more about the DOM itself with redraw or something.

First, is it really required to have that hidden in the DOM? If you append it by javascript it means you know the value, why not keep it in JS and inject it in the form on submit?
If it has to be in the DOM, try adding an empty `div` with `display:none;` and then put your data inside it so it can be used later...

I am unaware of mobile possibilities, but if it is the same as normal browser, you can work around it with my suggestions easily.

Comment: Ya, like you said, at first it should not be added to the DOM

Comment: @Salketer I have some data that is precomputed that I need to send across to the server for each request. Hence I have a hidden input element in the the html head that I need to re-post to the server on a form submit. Is fetching the value from the input element and injecting during a form submit computationally less expensive than the append? Is DOM redrawing a big factor for the hidden input element in this case. Please let me know

Comment: I really cannot tell about the redrawing factor... Why do you need to send it back to the server? Can't you just keep them on the server in a session or something?